# Laravel-Excel (MaatWebSite) takes to long reading

Tags: php, excel, laravel-excel

I dont know what im doing wrong, or maybe its something normal.
I have to load and "read" a excell with about 12000 rows.
I use this code for that.

```
Excel::selectSheetsByIndex(0)->load($path.$fileName, function ($reader) {
    $reader->each(function($row){
        Log::info('$row');
    });
});
```

As you can see, there is nothing heavy wich could make the read so slow.
I need to process hte data after the reading, so is a problem if only reading takes more than 5-10 minutes.

I tried also with the chunk filter, but nothing went better.

Is this normal?

I know excel reading is slow, as i read in other questions, but "this" slow?
Thank you.

Comment: Same problem, any update?

Comment: @abr I posted an answer, did it solved your problem?

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Laravel Fast Excel](https://github.com/rap2hpoutre/fast-excel) which aims to be faster. It has less feature, but it's OK for a simple XLSX import.

```
(new FastExcel)->import('your-file.xlsx', function ($row) {
    // Do what you want with this line, you can use it as an array.
    dump($row);
});
```